# SQL replace duplicate record with value based on condition

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am trying to create a report that shows a single item(store_Product) purchased by store location(store_ID).

There are total 3 types of store_Product: product_A, product_B, and product_C.
There are over a thousand unique store_ID.

My issue is that some unique store_ID have multiple store_Products and I need to shrink the query so it returns only unique store_IDs

These are the rules of condition:

- if a store has product_B and any other product, one unique store_ID record would have product_B as the store_Product value
- if a store has product_A and product_C, one unique store_ID record would have product_A as the store_Product value
- if a store has only one record then store_Product remains unchanged.

So the example below explains what I have on the left and what I want it to look like on the right:

[image]

I am using SQL server 2014 building the report in SSRS.

Really appreciate any help!

EDIT: What i have so far:

```
SELECT [store_ID]
  ,MIN(CASE WHEN store_product = 'product_B' THEN '1_product_B'
        WHEN store_product = 'product_A' THEN '2_product_A'
        ELSE '3_product_C' END) AS 'Prob_Group'
  ,CASE 
    WHEN (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Opened_Time, GETDATE())) * 1.0 / 60 < '24'
        THEN '0 - 24 HRs'
    WHEN (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Opened_Time, GETDATE())) * 1.0 / 60 >= '24'
        AND (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Opened_Time, GETDATE())) * 1.0 / 60 < '48'
        THEN '24 - 48 HRs'
    WHEN (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Opened_Time, GETDATE())) * 1.0 / 60 >= '48'
        AND (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Opened_Time, GETDATE())) * 1.0 / 60 < '72'
        THEN '48 - 72 HRs'

        ELSE 'Over 168 HRs'

        END AS 'Hour_Range'
FROM myTable 
WHERE *filters*
GROUP BY [store_ID]
        ,CASE 
        WHEN (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Opened_Time, GETDATE())) * 1.0 / 60 < '24'
            THEN '0 - 24 HRs'
        WHEN (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Opened_Time, GETDATE())) * 1.0 / 60 >= '24'
            AND (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Opened_Time, GETDATE())) * 1.0 / 60 < '48'
            THEN '24 - 48 HRs'
        WHEN (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Opened_Time, GETDATE())) * 1.0 / 60 >= '48'
            AND (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Opened_Time, GETDATE())) * 1.0 / 60 < '72'
            THEN '48 - 72 HRs'
            ELSE 'Over 168 HRs'
            END     
ORDER BY [store_ID]
```

Comment: We need some kind of detail here. This is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I have added the my code in the main post but the bottom half would not stay in code format.

My sample data returns duplicates of store_ID only when the hour range case statement is included. I tested without and it works fine. 

Please help me get in the right direction. I would be extremely grateful

Comment: You haven't add it sample data,  current and expected output. I wont try again until be sure what result should I get. And format the query properly.

Comment: I might be wrong and can;t test at the moment but you might be able to just add the CASE statement that @JuanCarlosOropeza gave in his answer to the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm being very sneaky here:

```
SELECT store_id, 
       MIN( CASE WHEN store_Product = "product_B" THEN "1_product_B"
                 WHEN store_Product = "product_A" THEN "2_product_A"
                 ELSE "3_product_C" 
            END) as Product
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY store_id
```

So if the store has `product_B`, the result would be `1_product_B`, not matter if are `product_A` and `product_C`.

Same if not `product_B` the minimum between `2_product_A` and `3_product_C` is `2_product_A` also works if only has `product_A`.

After you have the result you can remove the first two characters

```
WITH cte as (
    SELECT store_id, 
           MIN( CASE WHEN store_Product = "product_B" THEN "1_product_B"
                     WHEN store_Product = "product_A" THEN "2_product_A"
                     ELSE "3_product_C" 
                END) as Product
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY store_id
)
SELECT store_id, RIGHT(Product, LEN(Product) - 2) AS fixProductName
FROM CTE
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I forgot to mention one detail, I also have another column which is a case statement that determines an hour range based on the time of purchase.
So i have to include this case statement in the group me also. This is causing me to get duplicates. Here is what I have so far:

Comment: I have added my code in the main post since its too long to add in comments

Comment: I hate when this happen. You put the effort to answer the question and wasn't even the real question to begin with :(\

Comment: Im extremely sorry :( I thought it would help if i limit the amount of information i gave but I was wrong.